# How to side effect the dom from a ember.js view using observe?

Tags: ember.js

I have a simple view that attempts to hijack the DOM during an observer method like so

```
App.FooView = Ember.View.extend({
  whatever: function() {
    this.$("#foo").text("bar");
  }.observes('controller.foo'),
});
```

The problem I have is that during the observer callback, the selector always returns an empty DOM structure so I can't change the DOM in any way.

If I put a console.log inside this observes and the didInsertElement, I notice the observer is fired first, then the didInsertElement. How can I side effect the DOM with an observer like this?

Also some parts of my app don't invoke didInsertElement between the "controller.foo" changes so I'd need something that works w/out relying on didInsertElement specifically

(note- I know you don't usually drop down into "jquery soup" style coding w/ ember but for performance reasons I'm trying to attack my problem from a different angle. My model bound approach with pure handlebars doesn't scale at this time on a iPad2/3 and my customers don't want to rush out and buy the latest apple hardware just for my app it seems).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With your caveat that you have some sort of perf issue, I'd recommend scheduling it `afterRender`

```
whatever: function() {
  Em.run.scheduleOnce('afterRender', this, this.updateFoo);
}.observes('controller.foo'),

updateFoo: function(){
  this.$("#foo").text(this.get('controller.foo'));
}
```

http://emberjs.jsbin.com/zitayahi/1/edit

#### Side Bar

the cool thing with this, is if you wanted you could also do some debouncing if whatever it is you're doing is updating a billion times a second.

Comment: perfect ! Thanks again for the jsbin along with this blazing fast reply